# How to set all occurrence of a Variable in Section implicit

Tags: coq

Let's think of something like this `Section` as an example

```
Section myList.

Variable X : Type.

Definition myListApp2 (l1 l2       : list X) :=
  app l1 l2.

Definition myListApp3 (l1 l2 l3    : list X) :=
  app (app l1 l2) l3.

Definition NoXUse n := S n.

Definition myListApp4 (l1 l2 l3 l4 : list X) :=
  app (app (app l1 l2) l3) l4.

End myList.

Arguments myListApp2 {X}.
Arguments myListApp3 {X}.
Arguments myListApp4 {X}.
```

after the `End` of `Section` I need to set the first argument of all the definitions implicit by hand, is there any way to tell Coq that the `Variable X` is always implicit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`Context` command](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/language/gallina-extensions.html?highlight=context#coq:cmd.context) is a variant of `Variable` that allows this.

```
Section myList.

Context {X : Type}.

Definition myListApp2 (l1 l2       : list X) :=
  app l1 l2.

Definition myListApp3 (l1 l2 l3    : list X) :=
  app (app l1 l2) l3.

Definition NoXUse n := S n.

Definition myListApp4 (l1 l2 l3 l4 : list X) :=
  app (app (app l1 l2) l3) l4.

End myList.
```